# Sharing folders with X2Go?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, network-share, file-sharing, x2go

I just started using `x2go` to establish a remote desktop connection between two Debian 10 machines and discovered the neat file-sharing functionality of the `x2goclient` (*Session Preferences* > *Shared Folders*). I shared a local, client-side folder and noticed that it gets mounted on the remote server with the *full client-side directory path* automatically included in the folder/file system name - in this case `_home_username_Desktop_foldername (sshfs-disk)` according to its local path `/home/username/Desktop/foldername`.

Is it possible to customize the server-side folder name, e.g. in order to avoid disclosing the user name on the client machine or the folder's path, and is it possible to allow client-side read and/or write permissions while effectively blocking *deletion* of files? Are there any obvious security issues (or good practices) when using `x2go` or sharing folders with the `x2goclient`?

The shared folder is supposed to substitute the *non-functional bidirectional copy & paste* as a direct and convenient way to exchange files, without having to upload files to some 3rd party webspace (cumbersome) or even sending files by e-mail (even more cumbersome, file size limitations).